# appending string to char and vice versa

Tags: programming, string

Some days ago i started a thread.
[concatenation of non constant character array with a sting](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/concatenation-of-non-constant-character-array-with-a-sting)

I have a different question but on the same nature (string and chars)

what i want is one variable (string or char) that will hold a standard text and the value of gps coordinates latitude and longitude

The format is this: "latitude/longitude: 30.111111 20.111111"

What i have is a char that holds the standard text and the latitude: "Latitude/Longitude: 30.111111"

I also have another char that holds the second value (longitude)

The chars were generated with dtostrf():

```
char clat[10 + 20 + 1] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
char clng[10 + 1];
dtostrf(gps.location.lat(), 10, 6, clat+20);
dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 10, 6, clng);
```

I can also make the chars strings:

```
string1 = String(clat);
```

What have i tried:
1.Assigning clng to clat directly via dtostrf()

```
char clat[10 + 20 + 10 + 1] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 10, 6, clng+31);
```

It didnt work and got unexpected output

1. making clat a string and assign clng via for loop

   string1 = String(clat);
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
       string1[i+32]=clng[i];

This doesnt append it

I run out of ideas here.
Any help from more experienced guys?

Comment: Avoid using `String` at all costs! This is very bad for embedded programs. Take a lookk at my answer http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string/1033#1033 to see why

Comment: (See my updated answer to your [other question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/concatenation-of-non-constant-character-array-with-a-sting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it. was simple actually. dont know how to do it with chars, but with strings there is the addition operator.
So i converted both to string and used the + operator.

```
char clat[10 + 20 + 1] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
char clng[10 + 1];
String string1, string2, finalstr;
```

and inside the loop:

```
dtostrf(gps.location.lat(), 10, 6, clat+20);
dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 10, 6, clng);
string1 = String(clat);
string2 = String(clng);
finalstr = string1 + string2;
```

Maybe that was too much work?
If you have any smarter alternatives, please provide!

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is you do not need the `+` in:

```
char clat[10 + 20 + 1] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
```

You can just do this:

```
char clat[31] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
```

**A much simpler way to do this is this:**

Variables to initialize:

```
char subfinal[40] = "Latitude/Longitude: ";
String final = ""; //You don't need this, you could always use `String(subfinal)` instead
```

The code inside a function:

```
dtostrf(gps.location.lat(), 10, 6, subfinal+10);
subfinal[29] = " ";
dtostrf(gps.location.lng(), 10, 6, subfinal+30);
final = String(subfinal);
```

I haven't tested it, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: In C/C++, `char clat[31]` allocates 31 characters, not 32. The resulting elements are indexed 0 to 30 inclusive (i.e. there is no element 31).

Comment: @Peter Fixed that mistake..

Comment: I think it was I who started expressing array lengths as sums in an earlier thread w/ this OP. It isn't necessary to do but it documents why I made the array that long. The final sum is all the compiler cares about but '30+1' reminds me that I've allowed for the NUL terminator in my count. Likewise, '10 + 10 + 1' says I'm counting two strings and the terminator. It just serves to remind me how I arrived at the size.